# Are bash pipes lazy or eager?

Tags: bash, pipe

I was watching this command run

```
tar cf - 20180412 -P | pv -s $(du -sb 20180412 | awk '{print $1}') | gzip > 20180412.tar.gz
9.02GiB 0:01:20 [ 114MiB/s] [===================================================================================================================================================================>] 100%
```

and wondered how can `pv` work. I thought pipes were eager, but I think this `pv` can only work right if the pipes are lazy.

So, are bash pipes lazy or eager?

Answer (score 6):

Pipe behavior doesn't matter for the purpose of this command at all.

Although `tar` can start first, it usually feeds the pipe starting from the time zero so it will very soon block on a pipe and wait for `pv` to start consumption. In turn, `pv` doesn't even start before commands inside `$( )` start and finish.

Practically it doesn't matter if `pv` starts as soon as possible or waits for the first byte to appear on pipe (the answer is: as soon as possible, by the way).

What you might miss is that `du` estimates the input directory (not the tarfile) and at the same time `tar` reads  the same input directory on its own.